# Persisting PyTest data parameters across multiple test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, python-3.9

Is there a way from me to persist the "ref" parameters across multiple test cases inside the same Python script?

This setup "works", but it feels sub-optimal to have to copy/paste the same data for each test case.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('ref', [
    'crmpicco1872',
    'crmpicco2001',
    'crmpicco2008',
    'crmpicco2013',
    'crmpicco2021',
])
def test_data_directory_does_not_already_exist(ref):
    datadir = f"/var/lib/data/sites/{ref}"

    assert not os.path.exists(datadir)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('ref', [
    'crmpicco1872',
    'crmpicco2001',
    'crmpicco2008',
    'crmpicco2013',
    'crmpicco2021',
])
def test_data_directory_is_created(logger_fixture, config_parser_fixture, clean_context_fixture, ref):
    datadir = f"/var/lib/data/sites/{ref}"

    clean_context_fixture.data = "data0"
    clean_context_fixture.ref = ref

    create_data = CreateData(logger_fixture, config_parser_fixture)
    create_data.execute(clean_context_fixture)

    assert os.path.exists(datadir)
    shutil.rmtree(datadir)
```

Comment: Just move the parameter list to a global variable or function?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for the comment. How do I pass that function into each test case for example? Also, is a global variable good practice in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities: just extract the parameters into a function and use it in `parametrize`:

```py
def my_params():
    return [
        'crmpicco1872',
        'crmpicco2001',
        'crmpicco2008',
        'crmpicco2013',
        'crmpicco2021'
    ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('ref', my_params())
def test_data_directory_is_created(logger_fixture, config_parser_fixture, clean_context_fixture, ref):
    ...
```

Or set the parameters in the `pytest_generate_tests`, provided you always want to use the same parameters for the `ref` argument:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'ref' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        params = [
            'crmpicco1872',
            'crmpicco2001',
            'crmpicco2008',
            'crmpicco2013',
            'crmpicco2021'
        ]
        metafunc.parametrize('ref', params)

def test_data_directory_is_created(logger_fixture, config_parser_fixture, clean_context_fixture, ref):
   ...
```

Note that this is out of my head and may contain typos.